# Cannot access file system from Java Agent

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, agents

I want to check in the file system if file exists.
This code is working in SSJS and I can correctly see if the file exists or not:

```
var filePath = "/folder/temp.xlsx";
var inStream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
    if( inStream.open(filePath,"ASCII") ){
        if( inStream.getBytes()>0 ){

    ....

        }else{...}
        }else{...}
```

but this code, looking for the exaxt same file is not working in an agent: (!!)

```
    Session session =  getSession();   
    Stream inStream = session.createStream();
    String filePath = "/folder/temp.xslx";
    if( inStream.open(filePath,"ASCII")){
                  if(inStream.getBytes()>0){

    ...
    }else{...}
    }else{...}
```

It always goes into the 2nd else which means that inStream.open(file...) is false.

what is the difference between xpages file access and agent file access?
any solutions?

Comment: Where exactly is that file (absolute path)? I think current paths for agent and XP are different.

Comment: How is the agent run? In the AMGR? In the HTTP task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to increase the security level for the agent. To be able to access the file system from the agent.

[image]

Comment: Not only, agent must be signed with an ID, which is allowed to perform such operation.

Comment: "allow" is selected and the user has the rights needed. By the way both are very important and should be always considered in agents. it was my previous problem... :)

Comment: What if you try Java FileInputStream, you anyway write this in java, so why not using it? Also, have a look at java security policy file. On windows you can find it in Domino\jvm\lib\security\java.policy

Answer (score 1):

You might have to edit the permissions in your JVM.

Edit the file java.policy in the lib/security/ directory of the JVM of Lotus Domino.
For instance C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\security\java.policy

For testing you can grant all permissions like this:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

You have to restart the JVM. Most simple is to restart the server. But perhaps restarting http will do.

Comment: This will just make the server insecure. A more correct approach would be to use following, e.g. from http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frsec_javapolicy.html:
grant codeBase "file:user_client_installed_location" {   
permission java.io.FilePermission 
"C:\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib\ext\mail.jar", "read"; };